# ¿Porque se fuerza la descarga de un archivo excel?

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Estoy tratando de mostrar un archivo excel, pero este en vez de mostrarse lo que hace es que descargarse de una vez.

Asi trato de mostrar el archivo

```
public function ari(){

     $file = storage_path() . '\app\excel\formulario ORIGINAL ARI.xlsx';
     $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];

     return response()->file($file, $headers);
}
```

Sin embargo si trato con un archivo `pdf` no tengo ningun problema.

```
public function cardAval(){

    $file = storage_path() . '\app\pdf\carta-aval.pdf';
    $headers = ['Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'];

    return response()->file($file, $headers);

}
```

Asi el navegador me muestra el archivo y no fuerza la descarga como en el archivo `excel`, ¿Que tengo mal?

Comment: Tal y como lo tienes, depende del navegador hacer que se descargue o que se abra en una ventana. Si el navegador sabe cómo mostrar el tipo de archivo, por ejemplo porque tiene un lector de pdf, pues lo mostrará en pantalla. Si no sabe cómo mostrar un archivo, por ejemplo un excel, pues lo descargará para que lo abras con algún programa en local

Comment: pero si abro esos archivos desde mi correo si me los muestra en una nueva ventana, pero desde mi aplicacion los descarga de una vez

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes definidos los enlaces a estos archivos en tu aplicación: button, input, a href, etc?

Comment: desde una etiqueta  `a href`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En realidad no estas haciendo nada mal, los navegadores únicamente pueden visualizar archivos simples como txt, videos, audios, pdf y algún que otro que se me este escapando. Hasta donde sé, no se pueden visualizar archivos tipo excel, para eso se tendría que tener instalado algún plugin que permita visualizar este tipo de archivos directamente en el navegador. Pero dependería del usuario final instalar o no ese plugin.

Tú podrías forzar a que se visualizen ese tipo de archivos usando el visualizador de Google Drive:

```html
<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.comercial.usm.cl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/vica.com_.mx_Promociones_assets_promocion2.pdf" title="Quotes" target="_blank">http://www.comercial.usm.cl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/vica.com_.mx_Promociones_assets_promocion2.pdf</a>

<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.comercial.usm.cl/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/vica.com_.mx_Promociones_assets_promocion2.pdf&embedded=true" width="600" height="300" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Fuente: http://meridadesignblog.com/visor-archivos-pagina-web-con-google-docs-viewer/

Saludos!

Comment: Estoy tratando de hacerlo asi pana, y mi ruta quedaria `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://intranet/files/ari`, el problema es que no me muestra nada supongo porque la ruta no existe en la web, si no solo localmente, cuando suba la aplicacion a produccion seguira el mismo problema?

Comment: Efectivamente como mencionas, de momento te dará error ya que el archivo no puede ser accesible desde internet. Una vez tengas tu proyecto en un host y el archivo pueda ser accesible por medio de un dominio real, no creo que tengas el mismo problema. Solo debes considerar de que si vas a manejar archivos excel muy grandes (más de 1MB), quizás esta solución no te servirá de mucho. En ese caso la mejor alternativa será implementar [un viewer](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader) en tu propio servidor. Saludos!